# Laravel 5 - Strange behaviour I am ytrying to understand

Tags: php, laravel-5

Just trying to understand something.  A Project can have many Document.  In the Document Controller, I do this within the `create` function:

```
public function create(Project $project)
{
    $documents = Document::all();
    $documentLink = $_GET['documentType'];

    $document = Helper::findInCollection($documents, "name", $documentLink);

    dd($document);

    if ($document) {
        return View::make($documentLink.'Doc.edit', compact('project', 'document'));
    } 
}
```

So I essentially get all the documents.  I then get the document I am currently working on.  I then pass this to the edit view for that document. The `dd` displays the correct document to me, so this is fine.

In the edit view for that document, I also see the correct document I want if I do

```
{{ $document }}
```

So I know I have the correct `Document`.  The Form Model for this edit page is

```
{!! Form::model($project->document, [
    'class'=>'form-horizontal',
    'method' => 'PATCH',
    'route' => ['projects.documents.update', $project, $document]
]) !!}
```

So I am passing the route my `Project` Model and my `Document` model.  Now I would presume that `$document` would be the document I am working on.

However, in the update function, if I do

```
public function update(Project $project, Document $document)
{
    dd($document);

    return null;
}
```

It outputs an empty `Document`.  However, if I remove the type hint of `Document` from the functions parameters, it outputs the `id` of the document I was working on.

Why would this be the case?  Why does passing `Document` output an empty document, but removing this only shows the id of the current `Document`.

Any information appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It outputs an empty Document. However, if I remove Document from the functions parameters, it outputs the id of the document I was working on.
>
> Why would this be the case? Why does passing Document output an empty document, but removing this only shows the id of the current Document.

Simple answer is [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) and Laravels wonderful [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container).

By type-hinting `Document $document` Laravel will build you a new instance of Document from the container.

Without the type-hint your route would have defined something like the following; This is assumed that you bind the model Document to your document routes.

```
/document/update/{document}
```

Also, Laravel will **always** send in a Request object as the first parameter.